# Facebook SDK for JS: My feeds are not reflected on my friend's news feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the FB feed dialog, my posts are not appearing on my friends' news feed for some reason.

Here is my code snippet↓

```
 FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            app_id: 'XXXXXX',
            link: 'linkToASite',
            picture: imgUrl,
            name: 'imgTitle'
        }, function (res) {
                console.debug("res: ", res);;
       });
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: You can only post to your own timeline. If your app is in development mode then only you can see your posts.

Comment: I am not trying to post feeds on my friends' timeline directly.
When I post feeds on MY timeline, my friends should get notifications on THEIR timeline, shouldn't they?
Currently nothing appears ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the Status of Facebook Application.

Do this setting to fix the problem:

Go to Facebook Developer => You Application => Status & Review => set this option to YES:

"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"

Comment: To make your app public, you will have to have it reviewed by Facebook.